# NGINX Serve Static Files from Sub Folder Within Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, nginx

Running a ruby on rails application but have wordpress integrated under the /blog on the domain.

The problem I'm having is that none of the asset files are served correctly under the /blog url.

The wordpress php files are routed correctly and work.  The issue is that I'm trying to route the wordpress theme and plugin files, namely css and js files to the /blog folder. However I'm getting 404 for the static files served under /blog so I think I have a misconfiguration in my nginx conf file.

Current nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen       3000;
  server_name  myapp.com;
  access_log off;

    location /blog {
      location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|bmp|js|ico|swf)$ {
        expires max;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        root /var/www/wordpress/current/blog;
        break;
      }

      root /var/www/wordpress/current/blog;
      index index.php index.html index.htm;
      rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ /blog/$1 break;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
     }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|bmp|js|ico|swf)$ {
      root  /u/apps/myapp/current/public;
      expires max;
    }

    if (-f $request_filename.html) {
     rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
      expires max;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
      root /u/apps/myapp/current/public;
      break;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50M;
    root /u/apps/myapp/current/public;
     access_log off;
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/wrappers/ruby;
    passenger_enabled on;
passenger_max_request_queue_size 200;
    rails_env production;


    if ($host != 'myapp.com') {
      rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://myapp.com/$1  permanent;
    }

    location ~* ^/assets/ {
      expires 1y;
      add_header Cache-Control public;

      add_header Last-Modified "";
      add_header ETag "";
      break;
    }


    error_page   500 504  /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
      root   /u/apps/myapp/current/public;
    }

    error_page   502 503  /503.html;
    location = /503.html {
      root   /u/apps/myapp/current/public;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

     location ~ .*\.php$ {
    root /var/www/wordpress/current;
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS 'on';
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }

   location ~* "^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$" {
     add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between [root](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and [alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias), I think you're looking for `alias` in this situation.

When you use `root` nginx appends the URI to the path, so using `root /var/www/wordpress/current/blog;` will cause this to be the root directory for the request, which means navigating to `/blog/css/style.css` will cause nginx to look for `/var/www/wordpress/current/blog/blog/css/style.css`.

If you use an alias instead, then nginx will map the uri to the directory:

```
alias /var/www/wordpress/current/blog;
```

When you navigate to `/blog/css/style.css` nginx will remove the prefix and serve the file from `/var/www/wordpress/current/blog/css/style.css`, it seems you're attempting to do this with a rewrite however your rewrite is rewriting the request to the same uri.

In the situation the URL doesn't work your error_log should be your friend, it'll tell you exactly where it's looking:

```
2017/06/15 13:04:19 [error] 43391#0: *1786 open()
  "/var/www/wordpress/current/blog/blog/css/styles.css" failed 
  (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: myapp.com, 
  request: "GET /blog/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1", host: "myapp.com:3000"
```

Changing this to alias throws an error for me (because I don't have your directory structure) but it shows how the location changes:

```
2017/06/15 13:06:12 [error] 43582#0: *1787 open() 
  "/var/www/wordpress/current/blog/css/styles.css" failed
  (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: myapp.com,
  request: "GET /blog/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1", host: "myapp.com:3000"
```

You also don't have a lot of duplicate directives, you only need to define the them once as they are inherited by children, this can clean up your configuration file a lot making it easier to switch things around in the future:

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    listen               3000;
    server_name          myapp.com;
    access_log           off;
    root                 /u/apps/myapp/current/public; # default root, use this unless specified otherwise
    error_page           500 504  /500.html;
    error_page           502 503  /503.html;
    error_page           404      /404.html;

    location /blog {
        alias     /var/www/wordpress/current/blog; # overwrite the default root for this entire block
        index     index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|bmp|js|ico|swf)$ {
            expires    max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            break;
        }
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|bmp|js|ico|swf)$ {
        expires max;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        break;
    }

    location ~* "^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$" {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    if (-f $request_filename.html) {
        rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
    }

    if ($host != 'myapp.com') {
        rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://myapp.com/$1  permanent;
    }

    location ~* ^/assets/ {
        expires    1y;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header Last-Modified "";
        add_header ETag "";
        break;
    }

    location = /50x.html {
        root html; # overwrite the default root for this
    }

    location ~ .*\.php$ {
        root          /var/www/wordpress/current; # overwrite the default root, because this doesn't have /blog on the end it will properly map to /var/www/wordpress/current/blog when /blog is accessed

        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS 'on';
        include       fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }

    # this block is only processed if nothing else matches
    location / {
        passenger_ruby                   /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/wrappers/ruby;
        passenger_enabled                on;
        passenger_max_request_queue_size 200;
        rails_env                        production;
    }
}
```